# Xcode 4 crashes when opening project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

Full assertion is below!

I am trying to open our project on a fresh XCode 4 install (4.0.2) on a fresh new Sandy Bridge iMac Core i5.  This project worked and continues to work on my older MacMini and my partner's Core 2 Duo iMac.

I am suspecting this might be caused by this new machine never having had any older versions of XCode 4 or XCode 3 and the older SDKs ever installed onto it.  Just 4.02 and whatever comes with it.  Thats the only this I can think of ... and the only difference we know of between machines.  The file specified below indeed is not there ... so its a problem generating the PCH maybe???

Can anyone please help with this?

We cannot open our XCode project at all on the new machine and the assertion below is most unfriendly ...

Thanks!

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-287/Framework/Classes/Index/IDEIndex.m:2186
Details:  Error launching clang to create PCH file: /Users/sukichima/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LeapLanguage-gtjaysymsmxhiifrufylngcjwyxb/Index/PrecompiledHeaders/LeapLanguage_Prefix-bvjcknzwkkcgeydmvtyeuddafzgu_ast/LeapLanguage_Prefix.pch.pth
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"
Object:   <IDEIndex: 0x200c257c0>
Method:   -createPCHFile:willIndex:arguments:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x2036dfe80>{name = (null), num = 12}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000100949773 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010006d394 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000100564e3d __46-[IDEIndex createPCHFile:willIndex:arguments:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x0000000100005fdc __38-[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff88b6d4db dispatch_barrier_sync_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
  5  0x0000000100005f83 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x0000000100564a34 -[IDEIndex createPCHFile:willIndex:arguments:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x0000000100570b4c -[IDEIndexClangDataSource generateDataForFile:settings:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x00000001005706c1 -[IDEIndexDataSource processFile:settings:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x000000010056ffbe __70-[IDEIndex _indexFile:object:settings:afterOperation:beforeOperation:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
10  0x00007fff86976cc7 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
11  0x00007fff86a55af2 __doStart2 (in Foundation)
12  0x00007fff88b74284 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)
13  0x00007fff88b527f1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libSystem.B.dylib)
14  0x00007fff88b52128 _pthread_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
15  0x00007fff88b51fc5 start_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
rm -rf /Users/sukichima/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Or there’s a (very brief) [thread on Cocoa Builder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/301367-xcode-4-crash-on-project-open.html) that discusses the same issue. And what does `clang --version` say on your system?

Comment: Deleting the DerivedData folder does not solve the problem ... 

clang --version output:
Apple clang version 2.0 (tags/Apple/clang-139) (based on LLVM 2.9svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix

Comment: Works! make sure you change the user in the path to your own user name, of course.

Answer (score 6):

With me all the above didn't help. What DID help in the end was removing the 'xcuserdata' from the XCode project package. Apparently there were some corrupt user-dependent setting there.

Comment: Where can I find this file? I'm having pretty much the exact same problem as the OP.

Comment: Yourproject.xcodeproj -> (Right-click) -> "Show package contents"

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the file `~/Library/caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the source paths under XCode 4 preferences.  If you see the above error make sure you check your source paths and source path names with a fine tooth comb!

Comment: Perhaps you should mention what it is people should be searching for when they check their source paths and names with a fine tooth comb. It's all well and good checking them, but if you don't know what you're checking for then the exercise is pointless.